# Difference between function and search problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, search-problem

I am a bit confused on what the difference between a "function problem" and a "search problem" is.

The specific problem I have been studying is known as End-Of-The-Line:

> Given two functions, $P(x)$ and $N(x)$, a value $v$ is said to be balanced if $N(P(v)) = P(N(v)) = v \lor N(P(v)) \neq P(N(v)) \neq v$. Given that $0^N$ is not balanced, find another value that is not balanced.

How is this *not* a search problem? This problem is complete for the class $PPAD$ which is a class of function problems, but the problem is essentially asking us to search a graph for an unbalanced node.

From wikipedia:

> In the mathematics of computational complexity theory, computability theory, and decision theory, a search problem is a type of computational problem represented by a binary relation. Intuitively, the problem consists in finding structure "y" in object "x".

In End-Of-The-Line, the "y" structure is an unbalanced node that isn't $0$, and $x$ is the whole graph.

Is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: You can find a formal definition of a search problem at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem.  Please [edit] your question to describe the relation $R$ you want to define and explain why you believe it meets the conditions of that definition.  Your quote is not a formal definition; it is some informal English that is not a substitute for referring to the actual mathematical definition.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{PPAD}$ is a class of search problems, not of function problems. The notion of search problem is more general than that of function problem, which in turn is more general than a decision problem.

For a decision problem, we get an input and we need to answer *yes* or *no*.

For a function problem, we get an input and we need to compute a uniquely specified output.

For a search problem, we get an input and we need to compute some valid output.